# Redirect URL with query string to new "pretty" URL to avoid duplicate content

Tags: .htaccess, url, clean-urls

What the best .htaccess rewrite code to force URL like this one

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?page=report/tinytoes_mothercare
```

to that?

```
https://www.example.com/report/tinytoes_mothercare
```

My web site already resolve `https://www.example.com/report/tinytoes_mothercare`, so I want to avoid any duplicate contents with the ugly and bad URL above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing *rewrite* (that "resolves" the *pretty* URL) to redirect the old URL with a query string to your new *pretty* URL.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([\w/-]*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The first condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures we don't get a redirect loop by redirecting the rewritten URL. `REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty on the initial request, so only redirects direct requests from the client.

The second condition gets the necessary value from the query string `page` URL parameter. This matches characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore), `/` (slash) and `-` (hyphen) - as in your example URL. If you need to match more variation then the character class will need to be expanded. This value is then used in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string using the `%1` backreference.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change to a 301 (permanent) when you are sure it works OK, in order to avoid caching issues.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know!

Comment: It dosn't work..

my actual htaccess start with

`
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml sitemap.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
`

/////////////////////

If I add you code at topo of this, my bad url resolve like:
https://www.EXAMPLE.COM/report/report/tinytoes_mothercare?page=report/tinytoes_mothercare

Comment: Please edit your question to add the contents of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Ah sorry, you need the `QSD` flag on the `RewriteRule` to remove the query string from the redirected request. And I've removed the additional `/report` in the _substitution_ string. I've updated my answer.